# Installing specific CocoaPod - 'no such file' while processing pre-install hook

Tags: cocoapods

I installed MapBox on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with CocoaPods but I ran into a link problem and the MapBox people recommended that I download directly from a tag in their archive.  Unfortunately, I cannot get that tag to load.

Here's my Podfile with their suggestion:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'Mapbox', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk', :tag => '1.1.0'
pod 'TWTSideMenuViewController', '~> 0.3'
```

CocoaPods gets an error on the pod 'Mapbox' line (see below).  It does not seem to be able to find the directory.  I tried:

- fetching a particular :commit to see if it was that tag (no)
- changing the directory names to have only alphabetic characters (did not help)
- changing the Pod directory to allow writes by everyone (did not help)
- re-installing CocoaPods with sudo gem uninstall cocoapods, sudo gem install cocoapods (I got 0.29.0 again, but did not help get the tag sources)

Why is the pre-install hook unable to find (or create?) that directory?

Here's the output from 'pod install':

```
[!] An error occurred while processing the pre-install hook of Mapbox (1.1.0).

No such file or directory - /Users/Bob/Documents/InfoBridge/projects/infobridge_aboutmywoods-ios/Pods/Mapbox

/Users/Bob/Documents/InfoBridge/projects/infobridge_aboutmywoods-ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/Mapbox.podspec:25:in `chdir'
/Users/Bob/Documents/InfoBridge/projects/infobridge_aboutmywoods-ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/Mapbox.podspec:25:in `block (2 levels) in _eval_podspec'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:406:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods-core/specification.rb:406:in `pre_install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:489:in `run_spec_pre_install_hook'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:464:in `block (3 levels) in run_pre_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:462:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:462:in `block (2 levels) in run_pre_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:460:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:460:in `block in run_pre_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:113:in `message'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:459:in `run_pre_install_hooks'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:104:in `block in download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:101:in `download_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:87:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:38:in `run_install_with_update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:68:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.4.0/lib/claide/command.rb:213:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.29.0/bin/pod:24:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Thanks, Bob

Answer (score 2):

If you have previously installed Mapbox uninstall it first. Then install it again.

1. Remove or comment this line in Podfile

   `pod 'MapBox', '~> 1.1.0'`
2. Run command

   `pod install`

   This will remove Mapbox and all it dependencies.
3. Put back Mapbox to Podfile

   `pod 'Mapbox', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk.git', :branch => 'develop'`
4. Run `pod install` again

It helped in my case

Answer (score 0):

Remove podFile.lock and the problem is solved.